# custom sort a deck of cards

Tags: java, arrays

lets say i have a string array of shuffled cards

```
HK  C2  C8  CQ  S3  SJ  S4  D2  HQ  H9  HT  DT  ST  
H2  H3  SA  CA  HJ  S9  S6  S8  H8  H6  C7  D7  CJ  
H7  C9  DQ  DA  C5  D4  D6  D9  SK  DJ  CK  DK  SQ  
D5  HA  D3  S2  H4  S5  C3  D8  CT  S7  C6  C4  H5
```

How do i custom sort them into

```
S2  S3  S4  S5  S6  S7  S8  S9  ST  SJ  SQ  SK  SA  
H2  H3  H4  H5  H6  H7  H8  H9  HT  HJ  HQ  HK  HA  
D2  D3  D4  D5  D6  D7  D8  D9  DT  DJ  DQ  DK  DA  
C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7  C8  C9  CT  CJ  CQ  CK  CA
```

Currently I have tried, `Arrays.sort(stringArray)` method and i end up with

```
C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7  C8  C9  CA  CJ  CK  CQ  CT  
D2  D3  D4  D5  D6  D7  D8  D9  DA  DJ  DK  DQ  DT  
H2  H3  H4  H5  H6  H7  H8  H9  HA  HJ  HK  HQ  HT  
S2  S3  S4  S5  S6  S7  S8  S9  SA  SJ  SK  SQ  ST
```

After that, i tried to do an insertion method but ended up with

```
ST  SQ  SK  SJ  SA  S9  S8  S7  S6  S5  S4  S3  S2  
HT  HQ  HK  HJ  HA  H9  H8  H7  H6  H5  H4  H3  H2  
DT  DQ  DK  DJ  DA  D9  D8  D7  D6  D5  D4  D3  D2  
C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7  C8  C9  CA  CJ  CK  CQ  CT
```

This is what I've done so far

```
 Arrays.sort(stringArray); 

        for (j = 13; j < stringArray.length; j++) { 
          String  key = stringArray[j];
            i = j - 1;
            while (i >= 0) {
              if (key.compareTo(stringArray[i]) < 0) {
                break;
              }
              stringArray[i + 1] = stringArray[i];
              i--;
            }
            stringArray[i + 1] = key;
          }
```

EDIT: So i have to sort these elements in the following order: S,H,D,C
Also, it must be according to the rank of the cards. Thus,

> S2,S3,S4,S5,S6,S7,S8,S9,ST,SJ,SQ,SK,SA

Comment: What is the criteria that you sort the elements by? I can't see a formula.

Comment: Based on your required output you will need a method to compare two elements to determine their order.  It appears to be a complex set of rules to compare two elements.  Can you write the element comparison rules in plain language?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, i just updated my question

Answer (score 1):

Java `Collections` has a `sort()` method that takes both the collection to be sorted and a comparator. The comparator is a class with a method that takes two items of the type you are sorting and returns an indicator whether the first is less than, equal to, or greater than the other according to whatever rules it would like.

Put your items in a Java Collection, write your comparator, and let Java handle the sorting algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will give it a try now.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to represent each card as a String and three numbers or other values depending on your requirements.

```
class Card {
   String name;  // eg. AS, TD, 5H
   int rank;  // 0 - 12
   int suit;  // 0 - 3
   int value; // card rank 0 - 51.  rank and suit could be set using mod and div.

   public int getCardValue() {
       return value;
    }

    // other getters added here
    // ...
    public String toString() {
          return  name;
    }


}
```

Then you can just sort on the value using natural ordering (or some other ordering).
Assuming they are in a deck of type List of Card.

```
Collection.sort(deck, Comparator.comparing(Card::getCardValue));
```